# Problem with 5th gear

Tags: noise, corsa

getting a mechanic to look at it the weekend but wondered if anyone knew as it’s really worrying me, first time driver and I’m not clued up on cars really, but basically when I go into 5th gear (which I don’t do often as rarely go into high speed roads) my 5th gear will make an awful noise, the best way I can describe it is the car feels as if I’ve gone into 3rd gear, it will almost jolt slightly and make a loud engine sound (only I’m defo not in 3rd) , everyone told me it was probably because it doesn’t get used often and I was worrying too much, so the other day I drove about 10 mins at 45/50mph in 5th, when I stopped the car I could smell burning rubber coming from the engine (I’m aware this could have been awful clutch control from being so frightened of going into 5th) but either way I know something isn’t right with 5th and wondered if anyone can shed some light? It’s a 2008 Vauxhall Corsa, Thankyou x

Comment: A Vauxhall Corsa should drive fine at 40mph in 5th on a level road. Of course you don't have much acceleration in that gear, but if you are in a 40mph speed limit you don't need any! If you have horrible noises and burning smells, you need a garage to diagnose what is wrong. It might just be linkage between the gear lever and the gearbox that is stopping you engaging 5th properly (which is cheap and easy to adjust) or it might mean you need a new gearbox (which *isn't* cheap!)

Comment: Are you sure it hasn't gone into 3rd gear?  It may be that the gear lever linkages are worn and 5th is no longer selectable.  Is reverse gear just below 5th, or is that on the other side of the lever? Does the car have a rev counter?

Comment: To @HandyHowie 's point - try driving at say 40MPH in 3rd.  Note RPM. Shift to 4th. Then to 5th. Keeping speed at 40 MPH.  If RPMs the same in 5th as in 3rd , then you aren't really in 5th.

Comment: Hi all,im defo selecting 5th,but I’m sure it’s 3rd, I tried again yesterday, I was watching the Rev counter, and doing around 40mph when I select 5th the Rev counter will shoot up really high past the 30?

Comment: My reverse gear is by my 1st gear, also, I had the gear linkage replaced just before Xmas, however it was a friend that done it and he said although the part was to fit my car, it wasn’t an official Vauxhall’s part (I ordered off eBay) so he had trouble getting it on and basically had to force it on, so now I’m hoping it’s just that, getting it checked the weekend, thanks all x